# Is there a word or phrase for something you start but later abandon?

Tags: phrase-requests

Say, I started a long-term task, like a college degree, but real life happened before I could finish it, so I never did. Or I started to work on a submission but I couldn't finish it in time.

I thought about "never got the chance", or "never got around to it", but it doesn't capture the fact that I started it before stopping.

Comment: I call it "work".

Comment: Perhaps a [non-starter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-starter)?

Comment: You could say that you *never got around to **finishing** it*.

Comment: I think you are trying to cover too broad a context. Your three examples are widely different - task, degree and submission.

Comment: @Nigel J the thing is that in my native language (Hebrew), there is a single word that applies to all of those cases, since they are basically also tasks to you have to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say to have "squandered an opportunity" but that usually implies some fault or blame which might not necessarily be fair when talking about life generally getting in the way.

Potentially you could say that "life scuppered your college degree" or whatever example you care to use as it implies that life prevented you from succeeding in that task; which I believe also implies to a certain extent that you would have started that task.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a noun, consider ***abandoned activity*** or ***abandoned effort***:

> ***abandon***:
>     [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abandon):
>
>     If you abandon an activity or piece of work,
>       you stop doing it before it is finished.
>       *The authorities have abandoned any attempt to distribute food.*
>       *The scheme's investors, fearful of bankruptcy,
>         decided to abandon the project.*
>
> [Oxford US English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/abandon):
>
>     - Give up completely
>         (a course of action, a practice, or a way of thinking)
>         *‘he had clearly abandoned all pretense of trying to succeed’*
>
>       Discontinue (a scheduled event) before completion.
>         *‘against the background of perceived threats, the tour was abandoned’*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abandon):
>
>     to cease intending or attempting to perform —
>     *abandoned*
>     the escape
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=abandon):
>
>     To cease trying to continue; desist from: 
>       abandoned the search for the missing hiker.